# Why does this function cause an Access Violation if accessed via a pointer?

Tags: c++, c++11, crash

I have the following code:

```
void Aurora64::Messaging::SendConsoleMessageToPlayer(int channelId , const char *msg) 
{
    CGameRules *pGameRules = new CGameRules;
    pGameRules->SendTextMessage(eTextMessageConsole, msg, eRMI_ToClientChannel, channelId);
    delete(pGameRules);
}
```

It accesses a function in another class through pointer `pGameRules`, however the function causes the program to crash when it is called.

This code is inside the `Aurora64` class in another file.

---

When placing the following code inside the pointer's class `CGameRules` (in a function that is executed inside it), the program crashes:

```
CGameRules *pGameRules = new CGameRules;
pGameRules->SendTextMessage(eTextMessageConsole, "$4test", eRMI_ToClientChannel, channelId);
delete(pGameRules);
```

This was experimenting whether something in the `Aurora64` class file was causing the crash (it wasn't).

However when placed inside the same class, the program works perfectly with no crashes:

```
SendTextMessage(eTextMessageConsole, "$4test", eRMI_ToClientChannel, channelId);
```

Other than the pointer, the code is functionally identical (using the same input values).

Commenting out the `delete` calls has no effect.

---

The call stack is:

```
Aurora64.dll!IGameObject::GetEntityId() Line 301    C+Aurora64.dll!IGameObject::InvokeRMI_Primitive<CGameRules::MethodInfo_ClTextMessage,
          CGameRules::TextMessageParams>(const CGameRules::MethodInfo_ClTextMessage method, 
          const CGameRules::TextMessageParams
            & params, unsigned int where,
          IRMIListener * pListener, int userId, int channel, unsigned int dependentId)
          Line 281  C++
Aurora64.dll!IGameObject::InvokeRMI<CGameRules::MethodInfo_ClTextMessage,
          CGameRules::TextMessageParams>(const
          CGameRules::MethodInfo_ClTextMessage method, const CGameRules::TextMessageParams 
          & params, unsigned int where, int channel) 
          Line 275  C++
Aurora64.dll!CGameRules::SendTextMessage(ETextMessageType type, const char * msg, unsigned int
          to, int channelId, const char * p0, const char * p1, const char * p2, 
          const char * p3)
          Line 3075 C++
Aurora64.dll!CGameRules::OnClientConnect(int channelId, bool isReset) Line 596  C++
```

---

I don't understand why it's crashing... the code should technically work since the exact same function is being called, with the exact same input.

I have the [source-code on GitHub should it be required](https://github.com/AStopher/Crysis-Wars-Source-Code) (it does not have the `Aurora64` class as it's another project based on the one from GitHub, but the source hasn't been changed). It's also likely that to debug it the Crysis Wars game and dedicated server package would be required, making it harder for anyone here to debug.

The problem with this might be something really obvious that I'm missing.

What am I doing wrong?

---

The `SendTextMessage` method:

```
int CScriptBind_GameRules::SendTextMessage(IFunctionHandler *pH, int type, const char *msg)
{
    CGameRules *pGameRules=GetGameRules(pH);

    if (!pGameRules)
        return pH->EndFunction();

    int to=eRMI_ToAllClients;
    int channelId=-1;

    if (pH->GetParamCount()>2)
        pH->GetParam(3, to);

    if (pH->GetParamCount()>3)
    {
        if (pH->GetParamType(4)==svtPointer)
        {
            ScriptHandle playerId;
            pH->GetParam(4, playerId);

            channelId=pGameRules->GetChannelId((EntityId)playerId.n);
        }
        else if (pH->GetParamType(4)==svtNumber)
            pH->GetParam(4, channelId);
    }

    if (pH->GetParamCount()>4)
    {
        string p[4];
        for (int i=0;i<pH->GetParamCount()-4;i++)
        {
            switch(pH->GetParamType(5+i))
            {
            case svtPointer:
                {
                    ScriptHandle sh;
                    pH->GetParam(5+i, sh);

                    if (IEntity *pEntity=gEnv->pEntitySystem->GetEntity((EntityId)sh.n))
                        p[i]=pEntity->GetName();
                }
                break;
            default:
                {
                    ScriptAnyValue value;
                    pH->GetParamAny(5+i, value);
                    switch(value.GetVarType())
                    {
                    case svtNumber:
                        p[i].Format("%g", value.number);
                        break;
                    case svtString:
                        p[i]=value.str;
                        break;
                    case svtBool:
                        p[i]=value.b?"true":"false";
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }           
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        pGameRules->SendTextMessage((ETextMessageType)type, msg, to, channelId, 
            p[0].empty()?0:p[0].c_str(),
            p[1].empty()?0:p[1].c_str(),
            p[2].empty()?0:p[2].c_str(),
            p[3].empty()?0:p[3].c_str()
            );
    }
    else
        pGameRules->SendTextMessage((ETextMessageType)type, msg, to, channelId);

    return pH->EndFunction();
}
```

Comment: [OT] Why are you using a pointer here?  You should be able to just use `CGameRules pGameRules;  pGameRules.SendTextMessage(eTextMessageConsole, msg, eRMI_ToClientChannel, channelId);`

Comment: @NathanOliver Updated. I'll try that; my C++ is a little rusty (haven't had to use it for over two years), so I wouldn't be surprised if it would be something as simple as that.

Comment: You can remove the use of a pointer in this case but you should always test the result of the new() function to be sure that the dynamic allocation went well

Comment: What is the content of `SendTextMessage`?

Comment: @BenjaminNavarro You don't need to explicitly test it, because it would throw a `std::bad_alloc`.

Comment: @cybermonkey I meant, what the body (code) of the `SendTextMessage` method?

Comment: @Holt Updated. It's a large function and it hasn't been touched.

Comment: Your not mentioning what kind of crash it is, but the call stack indicates `CGameRules::SendTextMessage`, not `CScriptBind_GameRules::SendTextMessage` which you posted. The top of the stack being `IGameObject::GetEntityId()` hints that you could have an invalid `IGameObject`.

Comment: @molbdnilo It's an access violation, so it probably is. What could be causing it?

Comment: @cybermonkey Probably that you can't just create a `CGameRules` instance and start using it - it has to be set up properly. There's most likely only one in the program, created at startup, and you're supposed to use that.

Comment: @molbdnilo That did it! I [posted an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38103427/2422013) which references your comment, but if you want to post an answer yourself which explains the issue in more detail you can do (I'll delete mine and accept yours).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was overlooking the specific project's object system, as explained by [molbdnilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38102114/why-does-this-function-cause-an-access-violation-if-accessed-via-a-pointer?noredirect=1#comment63639944_38102114):

> Probably that you can't just create a CGameRules instance and start
>   using it - it has to be set up properly. There's most likely only one
>   in the program, created at startup, and you're supposed to use that.

I looked round the project for such an object, and I found it:

```
CGameRules *pGameRules=g_pGame->GetGameRules();
```